# Python: What is the usage of letter 'b' in hashing key with Blake2b

Tags: python

Does it really needed to use letter b when hashing a key? I'm just confused of its usage. Can I use the method 2 without using b'? And how can I insert a variable in method one?

```
from hashlib import blake2b

key = 'Hello'
blake2b(b'key').hexdigest()
```

versus

---

```
from hashlib import blake2b

key = 'Hello'
blake2b(key).hexdigest()
```

Comment: It means that it is actually a *binary string*: a list of bytes. But the bytes are here represented by their ASCII equivalent. The two are completely different. The fact that you write `key` has *nothing* to do with a possible variable `key`.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem So how can I insert the variable name within the blake2b() function?

Comment: Your second example above should work as you intend it to.  Does it not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: If you are using Python 2, `b'foo'` is identical to `'foo'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` in front of strings stands for **bytes**.

1. Your first example

   ```
   from hashlib import blake2b

   key = 'Hello'
   blake2b(b'key').hexdigest()
   ```

   Here you pass string `'key'` as bytes into `blake2b`. That doesn't insert the contents of variable `key`.
2. Second example:

   ```
   from hashlib import blake2b

   key = 'Hello'
   blake2b(key).hexdigest()
   ```

   inserts variable `key` but as a string and not its bytes representation.

What you want to do is

```
from hashlib import blake2b

key = 'Hello'
blake2b(key.encode()).hexdigest()
```

The last line constructs a string using `str.format()` which replaces `{0}` with first argument of `format`. By doing this you can prepend `b` in front of the string.

Comment: The string interpolation is probably unnecessary here.  `key=b'Hello'` would also work.

Comment: That is true, but you cannot do this if string gets from some other source, let's say `key = input()`.

Comment: bytestrings don't have a `format` method. You can convert `str` to `bytes` with `encode`.

Comment: I think I found the solution. Since I'm using Python 3.x, so it's mandatory to use b', what I did was this         from hashlib import blake2b
key = "b'Hello'"
blake2b(key).hexdigest()

Comment: Again, what if the `key` isn't typed there as it is but gets from other source?

Comment: Above example has been edited and tested...